# Extra tab creating in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

I am using SwiftUI for creating tab in iPhone. However it has creating extra tabs when I am trying to add two VStack in body.

'''

```
struct DemoView: View {
var body: some View {
VStack {
            Text("This is bug")
        }

VStack { //2nd Vstack
            Text("This is bug")
        }
  }
}
```

'''

for this 2nd VStack its creating two Demo tab
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My code to write TabBar
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEoKn.png

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code, which can’t be copied, pasted, searched, read by screen readers, etc

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to have multiple children in the body. you can put everything in either a VStack, HStack, Group, ZStack, or something of that sort depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

For example, if you want the 2 VStacks to be stacked vertically, you can wrap them all in a VStack like so:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack {
                Text("This is bug")
            }

            VStack { //2nd Vstack
                Text("This is bug")
            }
        }
    }
}
```